# Quantum algorithm's reflection clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation

5.5 Reflections

Given any unit vector a, we can create the unitary operator Ref a, which reflects
any other unit vector b around a. Geometrically, this is done by dropping a line
from the tip of b that hits the body of a in a right angle and continuing the line
the same distance further to a point b'
. Then b' likewise lies on the unit sphere
of the Hilbert space. The operation mapping b to b' preserves the unit sphere
and is its own inverse, so it is unitary.
In geometrical terms, the point on the body of a is the projection of b onto
a and is given by a' = a$\langle$a, b$\rangle$. Thus,
b' = b − 2(b − a$\langle$a, b$\rangle$) = (2Pa − I)b

where Pa is the operator doing the projection: for all b,
$P_ab$ = a$\langle$a, b$\rangle$.

Question: I don't understand why b' = b − 2(b − a$\langle$a, b$\rangle$) = (2Pa − I)b?

Answer (score 1):

If you break up $b$ into two components, one along the vector $a$ and the other orthogonal to $a$, we can then write $b$ as

$$
b \;\; = \;\; \underbrace{\left (b - \langle b,a\rangle a\right )}_{\perp} + \underbrace{\langle b,a\rangle a}_{||}.
$$

Now notice that $b'$ is obtained by reflecting the part of $b$ which is perpendicular to $a$, hence we get that

\begin{eqnarray*}
b' & = & -\left (b - \langle b,a\rangle a\right ) + \langle b,a\rangle a \\
& = & -b + \langle b,a\rangle a+ \langle b,a\rangle a \\
& = & -b + 2\langle b,a\rangle a \\
& = & b - 2b + 2\langle b,a\rangle a \\
& = & b - 2\left (b - \langle b,a\rangle a\right ).
\end{eqnarray*}

We get the identity by acknowledging that $P_ab = \langle b, a\rangle a$ and seeing that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
b' & = & b - 2\left (b - \langle b,a\rangle a\right ) \\
& = & b - 2b + 2P_ab \\
& = & 2P_ab - b \\
& = & (2P_a - I)b
\end{eqnarray*}

where we factor out $b$ and $I$ is the identity matrix/mapping.

Comment: ok and how does b - 2(b - $\langle$ b,a $\rangle$a) = (2$P_a$ - I)b?

Comment: Because $P_a(b) = \langle b,a\rangle a$.

Comment: is it -2*-$\langle$b,a$\rangle$a - 2*b = 2$P_a$ - 2b = (2$P_a$ -b)b? I don't see how to get (2$P_a$ - I)b, what's I? Is it 1, maybe 1001? Is it because any of the relations $B = A^{-1}$, $AB= I$, $BA = I$, $AA^{-1} = I$?

Comment: or because $P^T = 2P + I$?

Comment: @randomvalue I've augmented my post to answer your concern.  It essentially comes down to basic linear algebraic manipulations.